# PHP-exec plugin for wordpress not working in IE but is working in chrome

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome

Does anyone know of this issue? I've installed the php-exec plugin from the wordpress panel within my site. The odd thing is that its running / reading and displaying all my php code just fine on Chrome, but when I open IE it gives me this error:

```
Warning: file() [function.file]: Couldn't resolve host name in /home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42) : eval()'d code on line 13
```

Comment: If the paths of the includes used are based on what the client machine returns, this poses a very real security risk.
Please try to use <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/xxx.php'); ?>

Comment: Normally, everything that PHP-exec does can be solved with a Shortcode.